# How do I convert feet to inches in a string

Tags: vb.net

I have the following functions which detects and converts inches and feet in a string.

```
   'inches
   Private Shared Function Convert(value As String) As String
       Return Regex.Replace(value, "([\d.]+)'", Function(m) Format(Single.Parse(m.Groups(1).Value) * 0.3048, "Standard"))
   End Function

   'feet
   Private Shared Function ConvertFeet(value As String) As String
       Return Regex.Replace(value, "([\d.]+)''", Function(m) Format(Single.Parse(m.Groups(1).Value) * 0.0254, "Standard"))
   End Function
```

Please I want to combine these functions into one so than
eg. given 2'5'' I will have 0.74 meters
thus ' - means inch and '' - means feet

if there is any other way to achieve this I will gladly appreciate it

Comment: The question title appears to be misleading - you appear to be asking for a solution that converts feet/inches to metres.

Comment: _' - means inch and " - means feet_ - No ! ['] means feet and ["] means inch.

Answer (score 1):

If you can guarantee the string input will be in the correct format, this should work:

```
Private Shared Function Convert(value as String) as String
  Dim strParts as String() = value.Split("'")
  Return strParts(0).ToDouble()*0.3048 + strParts(1).ToDouble()*0.0254
End Function
```

Bear in mind the convention for feet and inches is usually the other way around, so `5'11''` would be 5 feet, 11 inches.